# NGINX + PHP5-FPM + DEPLOY - file permissions

Tags: php, nginx, deployment, ssh, debian

I have server with **Nginx**, **PHP5-FPM**.

I'm running 1 process in fpm pool with this configuration:

```
user = php-site
group = www-site

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm_web.sock

listen.owner = php-site
listen.group = www-site
listen.mode = 0666
```

I have these users:
- www-site (groups: www-site)
- php-site (groups: www-site)
- deploy   (groups: deploy, www-site)

This **deploy** user has only SSH access to do some stuff (composer, git deploy, etc..).

Problem is here, my application creates cache files in cache folder. Cache folder has **0775** (deploy:www-site), but *cache/template/file.cache* has **0644** (php-site:www-site). When I want to purge this cache folder, over `rm -rf cache/*`, I'm receiving `Permission denied`.

---

How could I solve it? If php5-fpm would create files with mask **0666** everything gonna be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways to do that:

1) Add umask to your base PHP scrip (`index.php`)

2) Add umask to your `php5-fpm` profile, to master process or single pool

3) Add umask to your unix user, user that php5-fpm or nginx runs (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)